# JQuery timeout issue with mouseout function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue with JQuery `mouseout` function and `setTimeout`.

What I want to achieve is that when I hover an element it changes the background. When I leave that element (so mouseout is triggered) the background should goes back to the original state after 1 second.

If I use the below code, `goBack` function is called only when I leave that element:

```
.mouseover(function(){
    changeBackground();
})
.mouseout(function(){
    //setTimeout(function() {
    goBack();
    //}, 1000);
});
```

But if I uncomment the timeout function (that is what I want to achieve), **even if I don't leave** that element, `goBack` function is called.

Any help or suggestion to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of bubbling of events so use [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter) and [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave) instead of mouseover and mouseout or use [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover) like,

```
.hover(function(){
    changeBackground();
},function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
       goBack();
    }, 1000);
});
```

or

```
.mouseenter(function(){
    changeBackground();
})
.mouseleave(function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
       goBack();
    }, 1000);
});
```

From the docs of `jQuery.mouseenter`,

> The `mouseenter` event differs from `mouseover` in the way it handles
>   event bubbling. If `mouseover` were used in this example, then when the
>   mouse pointer moved over the Inner element, the handler would be
>   triggered.This is usually undesirable behavior. The `mouseenter` event, on the other hand, only triggers its handler when the mouse enters the element it is bound to, not a descendant. So in this example, the handler is triggered when the mouse enters the Outer element, but not the Inner element.

Updated, here the issue with timeouts, you need to clear the timeouts which is before changing the background on mouseenter like

```js
function changeBackground() {
  $('#content').addClass('yellow');
}

function goBack() {
  $('#content').removeClass('yellow');
}
var t=null;//clear timeout variable
$(function() {
  $('#content').mouseenter(function() {
    clearTimeout(t);// clear previous timeouts
    changeBackground();
  }).mouseleave(function() {
    t=setTimeout(function() { //set new timeouts
      goBack();
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```css
#content {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: #ffff00 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  Lorem ipsum doner inut
</div>
```

Comment: I tried both, but the problem still occurs. If i enter or hover an element and uncomment the timeout, after 1 sec goBack is called even if I don't leave

Comment: By the way, I'd like to have timeout even with hover function. This is like a rating system I'm trying to implement, so I'd like to wait a sec before going back to the saved rating.

Comment: You can try your own my code here https://github.com/stestisa/star_rating and see that the issue still occurs

Comment: You got it! Thanks a lot.